# Crystal Report Print White Space Before Header When Use Custom Size

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I design a crystal report with size width = 5.847 and height = 8.269 but when i print it, there is a white space before header how to fix this?

I use the following code to print

```
Report print = new Report();

print.SetDataSource(ds);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = print;
print.Refresh();
print.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 0, 0);
```

Comment: That's a top margin.  Could be the print driver.

Comment: @JazzmanJim how to resolve this? In crystal report i set the margin 0